# Bootstrap Typeahead Displays Only 1 Character

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Ok I've read through all the other posts on this issue and tried about 30 different posted solutions that allegedly work but none of them work for me :(

First off some versions:

Bootstrap - 2.2.2, jQuery - 1.8.3, jQuery UI - 1.9.2

My XHR request returns the following JSON object when typing either a lower or upper case O:

```
[
   {"member_id":"6","name":"Jon Jones","member_group":"Default Group"},
   {"member_id":"2","name":"Vince Kronlein","member_group":"Default Group"}
]
```

My typeahead block looks like this:

```
$('.ajax-typeahead').typeahead({
   source : function(query, process) {
      return $.get('community/member/autocomplete', {
         filter_name : query
      }, function(data) {
         return process(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
   },
   property : 'name'
});
```

So when I begin typing, in this case the letter "O", I get a dropdown list that looks like this:

```
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
```

The seven O's correspond to the total number of times the letter O appears within the entire object but clearly, this isn't what I'm after.

The other thing I don't understand is that I can only type in a single letter and the dropdown  disappears.  The request is sent on each keydown and returns the object for each request, but the autocomplete ceases to work.

Need someone to tune me in to what the hell is going wrong here.

Thanks so much.

-V